# What's the average/median age of MSE?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know the average age of users on MSE. I've seen a wide variety, from middle schoolers to college students to statisticians to retired professors, and everything in between. If I were to estimate, I would put the median age to be around 25.

However, I would like to get this verified. This also would satiate my curiosity on how old/young people are, and the wide community MSE allows.

Thanks!

(As for me, I'm a teenager.)

Comment: I'm not sure that there is really any way of knowing.  Users are not required to disclose their ages (beyond declaring that they are over 13 years).

Comment: You're right... Would you think a median age of 25-30 be accurate? @XanderHenderson

Comment: I have no idea.  Again, I have zero data on which to base an estimate.

Comment: I'd guess the median rather quite a bit lower  21 maybe if that. (If one imposes a somewhat significant bound on points it might go up.

Comment: I believe it is mostly secondary school students, undergraduates, and postgraduate students on this site, plus a few professors and other people in academia (of which there are not that many of). An average age of 21 seems about right to me.